# Porque No funciona el 'WHERE' a una columna especifica? | SQL

Tags: sql

Buen Dia
Tengo el siguiente problema que no tiene tanta explicación ,Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Por alguna razón no me detecta la columna de Clasificación

Adjunto  imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto codigo :

```
 select * from balanzas  where Clasificación = 'Caja y Bancos'

 select  * From Balanzas where Nombre = 'Caja'

 'Caja y Bancos '
```

la definicion de la columna Clasificacion es `nvarchar(MAX)`
Espero que me puedan ayudar ,Gracias

> Bulk Insert

```
    CREATE  PROCEDURE SPI_Archivos         
@filePath varchar(max)              
AS               
BEGIN        
  SET LANGUAGE Spanish;        
      
  CREATE TABLE #TempTable (        
    Cuenta nvarchar(max),        
    Nombre nvarchar(max),        
    Monto float,        
    Fecha DATETIME,        
    Clasificación varchar(max))        
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM ''' + @filePath + ''' WITH (FIRSTROW=2, ROWTERMINATOR =''0x0a'' )';               
  EXEC (@sql);        
        
  Insert into Balanzas      
  select * from(      
  select Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación from #TempTable      
  except       
  SELECT Cuenta,Nombre,Monto,Fecha,Clasificación from Balanzas) p      
  END
```

> Datos del txt

```
    Cuenta  Nombre  Monto   Fecha   Clasificación
000-0100    ACTIVO  15624479.33 2018-01-01  Activo
000-0110    CIRCULANTE  12217210.9  2018-01-01  Activo Circulante
101-0000    Caja    4000    2018-01-01  Caja y Bancos
101-0100    Caja Monterrey  4000    2018-01-01  Caja y Bancos Sub
```

Todo esto lo utilizo para un stored procedure :

```
    Alter  Procedure SPQ_Total_Estado                                            
@FechaNuevoFormato1 DATETIME,                      
@FechaNuevoFormato2 DATETIME                     
AS                      
 BEGIN              
 SELECT     Clasificación,
   SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= CONVERT(DATE, @FechaNuevoFormato1) AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATE, @FechaNuevoFormato1)) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFecha1,          
   SUM( CASE WHEN Fecha >= CONVERT(DATE, @FechaNuevoFormato2) AND Fecha < DATEADD( MONTH, 1, CONVERT(DATE, @FechaNuevoFormato2)) THEN Monto ELSE 0 END) AS TotalFecha2          
  from Balanzas    where Clasificación like '%Caja y Bancos%'     

  group by Clasificación

  END
```

y en el where pongo la clasificacion y ahi se encuentra el problema

Comment: Que quieres decir con "no me detecta"

Comment: Puedes intentar sin espacios en el select * from balanzas where clasificacion ='Caja y Bancos' o probar sin la tilde tanto quitarsela a la columna de la tabla select * from balanzas where clasificacion ='Caja y Bancos' y como ultima opcion select * from balanzas where clasificacion like 'Caja y Bancos'

Comment: Hola @Japv el primer  select * from balanzas where Clasificación = 'Caja y Bancos' no detecta que hay datos que si coinciden a Caja y Bancos

Comment: y en el segundo select se puede notar que la columna Clasificacion si tiene esos datos

Comment: 1) Te has dado cuenta que en en el `where` estás buscando `Caja y Bancos` con un espacio final? será eso? 2) Por otro lado, por favor deja de adjuntar imágenes ya que además que te va a resultar más fácil pegar el código nos harás la vida mas simple a los que eventualmente te podríamos ayudar, ten en cuenta además que en la comunidad hay personas con problemas visuales y pegar una imagen no es lo ideal para ellas.

Comment: Por favor agrega le definición de la columna `Clasificación`

Comment: Ten mucho cuidado con los espacios y otros caracteres que no son visibles, usa el operador like  %palabra%

Comment: @japv Me funciono con el LIKE Pero tengo otros datos que se llaman "Caja y Bancos Sub " y tambien me los trae ,como puedo evitar eso y especificar el dato correcto

Comment: Bueno, puede haber cualquier tipo de carácter, incluso no visible, en la columna, revisa la longitud de `Clasificación`  para `Caja y Bancos`, deberían ser 13 caracteres, si son más es señal que hay algo más en esa columna. Para salir del paso puedes intentar `where left(Clasificación, 13) = 'Caja y Bancos`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Si me funciono, pero tambien me trae 'Cajas y Bancos Sub'

Comment: @PatricioMoracho la longitud es Max tipo nvarchar de la columna Clasificacion

Comment: Lo que olvide mencionar es que los datos los obtengo desde un bulk insert ,de un archivo txt,

Comment: Cualquier varchar como su nombre lo indica es de longitud variable, revisa el tamaño con `LEN(Clasificación)`, también te sugiero que copies una o dos filas del archivo del BULK insert en  esta pregunta a ver si eso nos da una pista.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Actualice la pregunta con el bulk y algunos datos del txt ,

Comment: @PatricioMoracho y hice el Len(Clasificacion) y los datos son variables ya que tengo varias clasificaciones

Comment: El uso de la tilde en el diseño de tablas de datos, no se aconseja. Intenta quitarla en el campo aludido.

Comment: El tema es hacer  el LEN en los casos de  `Caja y Bancos`, si no hay caracteres de más la longitud debería ser de 13, si hay espacios o incluso caracteres no imprimibles debería ser mayor. En el ejemplo que has compartido del archivo de bulk insert lamentablemente no se aprecia nada raro.

Comment: no corras más de una consulta ala ves, y si lo haces colócale el delimitador, generalmente es `;` y va al final de cada enunciado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Logre solucionar el problema ya que en el bulk insert no tenia esto `ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'`  y solo la puse y ya funciono

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, agrega más detalles para ampliar tu respuesta, como código que funcione o citas de documentación.

Comment: Que tendra que ver el bulk insert con el select... o sea, tus campos no tenian lo que vos pensabas que tenian???